# How do you sync Jorte with an Outlook Calendar?

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange, jorte

I am trying to convince my wife to switch from the Motorola stock calendar app to Jorte. Is there a way to synch Jorte with your Outlook calendar? If not, is there another calendar app that beats the pants off the stock one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Jorte's description](https://market.android.com/details?id=jp.co.johospace.jorte), it looks like you can synchronize Jorte with Google Calendar. You can also synchronise Outlook with Google Calendar using [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955).

So if you're happy using Google Calendar as a "middle-man" then it would be possible to sync the two.

Comment: Thanks. I really would rather not route the Outlook calendar through Google Calendar. I was hoping there was another option for synching your Outlook Calendar and Google Calendar to the same calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

Try the app [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client). Free to download at Google Play. Easy to sync Outlook on PC to Android smartphone and Jorte. Works like a charm.